# i am getting error while trying to import go package. who could be appropriate solution for this problem?

Tags: go, import, package

could not import myproject/game/helper2 (cannot find package “myproject/game/helper2” in any of
/usr/local/go/src/myproject/game/helper2 (from $GOROOT)
/home/prasnjit/dev/go/src/myproject/game/helper2 (from $GOPATH))compiler

the screen shot of code is attached below
screenshort is given below. Give me some useful solution of it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOoNU.png)

i am trying to import one package in main.go and getting error while importing. i am not able to configure what could be the problem.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Show actual content of go.mod and actual import paths.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your module is called "myproject" (this is declared in `go.mod`). It looks like you want to import the "game" package instead.

```golang
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "myproject/game"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(game.Get())
}
```

In Go, you import *packages*, not files. Packages are typically organized in directories. Go source files declare the package that they belong to on top. Learn more about Go modules [here](https://go.dev/ref/mod).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing the import wrong.

try like this

```
import "myproject/game"
```

If you are importing a package,no need to mention the filename.
[Checkout this](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/call-module-code)